# Файл kml в blade шаблонизаторе

Tags: laravel

Как разрешить подключение файла .kml в шаблоне Laravel

Answer (score 0):

Если я не ошибаюсь было что-то такое `View::addExtension('kml', 'php');` добавьте перед тем как пытаетесь подгрузить ваш шаблон,

Более подробно в классе namespace Illuminate\View\Factory

```
/**
 * Register a valid view extension and its engine.
 *
 * @param  string    $extension
 * @param  string    $engine
 * @param  \Closure  $resolver
 * @return void
 */
public function addExtension($extension, $engine, $resolver = null)
```